# Alguém me ajuda algo esta errado aqui tem 3 erros e não sei tirá-los! C#

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Velocidade do Jogador
    public float speed = 6f;

    //Vetor responsavel pelo movimento
    Vector3 movement;
    //Responsavel pela transliçao da animaçao
    Animator anim;
    //Responsavel pela fisica do objeto
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    // Mascara de chao
    int floorMask;
    //Inf para raycast
    float camRayLenght = 100f;

    void Awake()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");

        //atribuir as referencias
        anim = GetComponents <Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

        movement (h, v);
        Turning ();
        Animating(h,v);

    }


    //movimento
    void move (float h, float v)
    {
        //dertemina o movimento
        movement.Set (h,0f,v);

        //normaliza o movimento
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //efetua o movimento no personagem
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }


    //girar o jogador
    void Turning()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(camRay,out floorHit,camRayLenght,floorMask))
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - Transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);


        }


}

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v!=0f;
        anim.SetBool ("IsWalkin", walking);


    }

}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está parecendo aqueles passatempos que vêem em revistas: **Descubra as 6 diferenças**

Comment: Se tiver as mensagens de erro, edite a pergunta e adicione eles ou descreve o resultado inesperado e qual seria o certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude ver, primeiro erro está em:

```
anim = GetComponents <Animator> ();
```

que deveria ser:

```
anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
```

---

O segundo erro está em:

```
movement (h, v);
```

que deveria ser:

```
move (h, v);
```

---

O terceiro erro está em:

```
Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - Transform.position;
```

que deveria ser:

```
Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
```

---

Isso corrige os erros, mas não posso garantir que a lógica do script está correta.